# Transformação de dados

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Salve galera, beleza?

Estou com um problema e não sei como resolve-lo... Estou com um conjunto de dados sobre o Netflix e Disney+, estou fazendo uma analise exploratória e comparando os dados.

Estou querendo analisar o quanto de tempo que vamos gastar caso queiramos assistir toda a programação que a Netflix e o Disney+ fornece.

Porém não estou conseguindo fazer uma transformação necessária na coluna "duration". Não estou conseguindo separar os filmes das series para fazer os cálculos que desejo fazer.

Como posso fazer tal separação?

[image: Dataset]

[Link para o notebook no Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/joaomouras/netflix-disney)

Comment: ```data_net_clean['Movie'].duration```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa tudo bem?

Você pode começar separando seu dataframe em dois diferentes, um para séries e um para filmes. partindo do pressuposto que todas as series tenham a palavra "Season" e todos os filmes tenham a palavra "min" você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
series = data_net_clean[data_net_clean['duration'].str.contains('Season')]
filmes = data_net_clean[data_net_clean['duration'].str.contains('min')]
```

Comment: Valeu, funcionou direitinho!